# Create publishable tables from stat outputs

Tags: r, statistics, output, publish, tabular

I wonder if anyone can point me towards something in which I can make nice publishable tables from outputs from different stat tests, either in **R** or from other software.

Right now, I have a large messy output in .txt (from a script using scipy/numpy) format and an output from the ks.test in **R**. 
I've looked some at xtable in **R**, for the output from the ks.test. But when assigning the output from the ks.test to a string, e.g. ks=ks.test(x,y) and then try to use xtable, I'm getting the error:

> no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "htest"

The format of the tables would preferably be in .pdf or .eps (not embedded).

Comment: What format do you need the table marked up in? (I.e. what are you writing your document in?)

Comment: The publisher wants it either in MS word/excel format or pdf... So I would go for pdf.

Comment: OK, so a PDF. How are you producing that PDF. From Word, LaTeX? Or do you mean they want the table as a PDF file itself, not embedded? Can you edit the question to include example of how you want the table to look, what info etc.

Comment: In addition, a reproducible example would be nice as `can't get it to work` is very vague.

Comment: If you have only a single `ks.test()` result or one or two, I wouldn't bother with a table. Just quote the test statistic, and p-value in-line in the text; "The two populations were found to differ (KS test, D = x.xx, p = 0.002)".

Answer (score 4):

If you want to produce LaTeX tables, you can either use the `xtable` package, or use `latex` from the `Hmisc` package. You can render LaTeX files to pdf, so that might be acceptable for the publisher.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your tables to be printed in LaTeX or HTML format, you could try the `xtable` package. For example:

```
my.R.table <- matrix(runif(21), ncol=3)
my.x.table <- xtable(my.R.table,
                     caption = c("The long caption for this",
                                 "The short caption"),
                     label = c("my.latex.label"),
                     align = c("l", "l", "r", "c"),
                     digits = 3)
print(my.x.table, caption.placement = "top",
      include.rownames = FALSE, type="html")
```

For statistical models there also exists a package called `stargazer`. I have not tried this one though.

Answer (score 3):

The error you show is because the output from `ks.test` is not tabular output nor in a format that `xtable` understands. The output looks like this:

```
> x <- rnorm(50)
> y <- runif(30)
> # Do x and y come from the same distribution?
> (res <- ks.test(x, y))

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y 
D = 0.46, p-value = 0.0004387
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Which isn't really tabular. For you to get this to work with `ks.test` you'd need to write a method for `xtable` for class `"htest"` (which is what type of object is returned by `ks.test`. Several methods already exist for other types of object:

```
> require(xtable)
Loading required package: xtable
> methods(xtable)
 [1] xtable.anova*           xtable.aov*            
 [3] xtable.aovlist*         xtable.coxph*          
 [5] xtable.data.frame*      xtable.glm*            
 [7] xtable.lm*              xtable.matrix*         
 [9] xtable.prcomp*          xtable.summary.aov*    
[11] xtable.summary.aovlist* xtable.summary.glm*    
[13] xtable.summary.lm*      xtable.summary.prcomp* 
[15] xtable.table*           xtable.ts*             
[17] xtable.zoo*            

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Class `"htest"` is reasonably common (it is used for most it not all of R classical tests), so I would venture that the absence of an `xtable.htest` is that the results from a hypothesis test like this don't lend themselves to tabular output - there are only two numbers of interest in the KS test output for example.

As I said in my comment, I would just quote the test statistic `D` and the `p-value` in-line in the text.

If you have multiple tests and want to summarise them, collect the outputs from several `ks.test` runs into a data frame and then use `xtable` on that data frame (which will work as it there is a method for that). To combine to a number of ks tests into a table (a data frame) you could do something like

```
df.res <- data.frame(D = c(res$statistic, res$statistic),
                     `p value` = c(res$p.value, res$p.value))
xtable(df.res)
```

which gives:

```
> df.res <- data.frame(D = c(res$statistic, res$statistic),
+                      `p value` = c(res$p.value, res$p.value))
> xtable(df.res)
% latex table generated in R 2.15.2 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Wed Oct 31 09:19:16 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 & D & p.value \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0.46 & 0.00 \\ 
  2 & 0.46 & 0.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Then look at `print.xtable` and the manual for **xtable** the package for details of how to format the names of the data frame etc to get nicer output in the LaTeX output.

Comment: Yeah, I have quite a few outputs I would like to combine in a table. Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Ok, I have added an example of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider the `pander` package as another way to format output.  It has several options for the final type of file to create and does have a method for `htest`s.

But for publication you often don't want the same format as the default output, it is better to extract the key pieces from the htest object and format them yourself.  Tools like `sweave` and `knitr` can be used to create the format you want and insert the important information into your format.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the stat test you are using, a great option could be sjPlot: http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/

A few of its options are:

- sjt.corr - correlations as HTML table
- sjt.lm - linear models as HTML table
- sjt.lmer - linear mixed models as HTML table
- sjt.pca - principal component analysis as HTML table

Using the "file" parameter you can save the output.

```
library(sjPlot)
sjt.lm(fitted_model, file = "file_name.pdf")
```

An example of a publication ready table for a linear model using the above code(from: http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjt.lm/):

[image]